# Workflow for getting email's two days before the date

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have `joining date` as a column in a list. |Based on joining date I need mails to be triggered 2 days before the given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 calculated columns: 
1. One column to calculate joining date - 2 days. Like so: `=[Joining Date]-2`
2. Second column to extract the above difference in dd-mm (or mm-dd) format. Like so: `=TEXT([Joining Date],"dd-MM")`

In the workflow, format today's date as dd-mm or mm-dd and compare it with the 2nd column. If it is similar, send an email.

Refer [this](https://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/quick-tip-get-todays-date-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) to get today's date and refer [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/get-datepart-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow) to get the datepart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Pause until date" activity of SharePoint designer Workflow.

For reference: [Pause until date](http://www.smellslikesharepoint.com/2012/06/26/sharepoint-2010-workflow-pause-until-date-and-time/)